# Why is rake aborting because of libpq.5.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, libpq

I just installed **PostgreSQL** and the **pg** gem for running Rails on Heroku. I'm running

```
$ rake -T
```

But it's aborting for reason related to "libpq.5.dylib"

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

What gives?

How can load the libpq.5.dylib library?

Answer (score 4):

I am on a Mac. Here is what I did to get it working.

```
cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/
otool -L pg_ext.bundle

libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.4.0)
```

Notice that libpq.5.dylib doesn't use an absolute path like the other libs in pg_ext.bundle. The system can't find it. You need to change where it looks for libpq.5.dylib.

```
install_name_tool -change libpq.5.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib pg_ext.bundle
```

Note: Use the absolute path that applies to your system. I used what it was for my system.

Now run:

```
otool -L pg_ext.bundle
```

Notice what libpq.5.dylib points to now:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.4.0)
```

The pg gem should be happy now.

Comment: Here's another approach that may work if you're running into this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627465/ruby-pg-gem-linking-to-wrong-copy-of-libpq-5-dylib-on-osx

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion [here](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/32/installation-problems-on-mac-os-x-snow) it seems like compiling *64-bit Ruby*'s pg against *32-bit Postgresql* is the source of the problem.
So the only way to solve it is to install 64-bit Postgresql and then reinstall `pg`.

[This post](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/32/installation-problems-on-mac-os-x-snow#comment-194269) explains the issue in detail.

Comment: Thanks- running a `bundle pristine pg` fixed a similar issue for me.